# Why am i getting argumentNullException when adding migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I'm trying to create a migration in my web api for one-to-many db. Services are configured this way and the connection string is successfully received from launchsettings.json

```
var connectionStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApplicationDbContext");

services.AddDbContext<InsolationResultContext>(options =>
{
options.UseNpgsql(connectionStr, builder =>
{
        builder.CommandTimeout(300);
        builder.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), null);
      });
});
```

This are models

```
public class DocumentInsolationResult
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<InsolationResult> Elements { get; set; }
    }
public class InsolationResult
    {
        public string UniqueId { get; set; }

        public string Insolation { get; set; }
    }
```

And DbContext

```
public class InsolationResultContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<DocumentInsolationResult> DocumentInsolationResults { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InsolationResult> InsolationResults { get; set; }

        public InsolationResultContext(DbContextOptions<InsolationResultContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentInsolationResult>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Elements)
                .WithOne();
        }
    }
```

the connection string looks like this:

```
"environmentVariables": {
        "ApplicationDbContext": "Host=192.168.1.***;Port=****;Database=***.******;Username=*****;Password=****",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
```

When trying to "Add-Migartion Init i always get "Value cannot be null. (Paramtere 'connectionString'). What am i doing wrong? Coulnd't actually find the answer on the internet

upd: i'me receiving the connection string from launchsetting, it's ok as i'm using the same way of getting connectionString on some other projects

upd2 hardcoding the connection string worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you use IConfiguration instead of Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable then it becomes a lot easier:

```
var connString = config.GetValue<string>("ApplicationDbContext");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ApplicationDbContext": "Host=192.168.1.***;Port=****;Database=***.******;Username=*****;Password=****""
  }
```

in appsettings.Development.json file.

Thus it is giving error "Value cannot be null. (Paramtere 'connectionString')."

And in your startup.cs file

```
services.AddDbContext<InsolationResultContext >(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContext")
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work. The connection string is successfully received form launchsettings, so moving it to appsettings and changing the way of getting it doesn't work. still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was really with the connection string. I couldn't create a migration when using connection string from appsettings or launchsettings. After hardcoding the connection string in stratup.cs i was able to create migration. And now after the db is initialized i'm using connection string from launchsettings. This might be some EF core tricky things.